# Returning a list of 'Chip' Widgets on Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

I am trying to build a class that I can call in my main code. This class is meant to take the user's input, stored as a  of String and, this  is to be iterated through, and generate 'Chip' Widgets where each of the iterated String is passed into a 'Chip' constructor where the String becomes the title (or label).

When I try to **return** the widgetList, I get the following error:
*Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.*

```
class ChipSection extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> userList;

  const ChipSection({Key? key, required this.userList})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgetList = [];
    for (int counter = 0; counter < userList.length; counter++) {
    String word = userList[counter];
    widgetList.add(Chip(
        label: Text(word),
        onDeleted: () {
          print('I am deleted');
        }));
           
    }
    ;
    return Container(widgetList);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how should I recode this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For list you need to use a widget that use children instead of single child[widget]. For `Chip`, `Wrap` widget is perfect.

```dart
 return Wrap(children: widgetList);
```

More about [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.htm)

Comment: I am so grateful for your help! This was a problem I have been struggling with for a long time. You helped me so much! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the `build` method you can only return one widget. If you want to return many chips, you must wrap them in another widget that receives `children`. You can use [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) to align the chips vertically, [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) to align horizontally, or [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) to make them horizontally aligned with line breaking.

I would write this widget as follow:

```dart
class ChipSection extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChipSection({super.key, required this.words});

  final List<String> words;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      children: [
        for (final word in words)
          Chip(
            label: Text(word),
            onDeleted: () {
              print('I am deleted');
            },
          ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

[Click here to see a live demo.](https://dartpad.dev/?id=8e562b9f63095946301b9a5827dde84d)

See you!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering indicates that you are passing an extra positional argument in your code, while the Container method does not take any positional argument.

In fact, in the last line of the build method, you are passing the list of created widgets directly as an argument to Container, while this method expects a value for its named parameter "child".

You can simply wrap the list of widgets in a Column widget, which will serve as a container for the list of widgets.

```dart
class ChipSection extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> userList;

  const ChipSection({Key? key, required this.userList})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgetList = [];
    for (int counter = 0; counter < userList.length; counter++) {
      String word = userList[counter];
      widgetList.add(Chip(
          label: Text(word),
          onDeleted: () {
            print('I am deleted');
          }));
    }

    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: widgetList,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or with Wrap widget :

```dart
class ChipSection extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> userList;

  const ChipSection({Key? key, required this.userList})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgetList = [];
    for (int counter = 0; counter < userList.length; counter++) {
      String word = userList[counter];
      widgetList.add(Chip(
        label: Text(word),
        onDeleted: () {
          print('I am deleted');
        },
      ));
    }
    return Wrap(
      children: widgetList,
      spacing: 8,
      runSpacing: 8,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's very helpful! Thanks for the additional knowledge too.